# Is there a way to disable "Top Hits" in the Safari 6 address bar?

Tags: macos, safari

The Top Hits section of the suggested results list that appears when I type in the Safari address bar proposes sites that are way off base.

[image]

Is there a way to remove Top Hits from the address bar's suggested results, or at least "demote" the Top Hits section so that it is not the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Top Hits section uses the top two sites from your history, so if there are certain sites you don't want showing up in Top Hits, just press <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, and delete the offending sites. (I don't know how to remove it though.)

**Edit:**

As noted in the comments below, the keyboard shortcut to access History is now <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>.

Comment: Using Safari 11.0.3, Option-Command-2 seems to resize text on displayed web page!

Comment: Command Y brings up History where the offending lines may be deleted.

Comment: It must have changed! I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers are very incorrect.  The Top Hits does not come from your history and changing the settings for providing suggestions has anything to do with the Top Hits.

The Top Hits section pops up suggestions from websites that you have saved as a favorite.  I have not found a way to disable the Top Hits, but if there is a website that you do not want to pop up, you have to delete it from your favorites.

Comment: Any references for this view - the OP seems to think the others are correct

Comment: That can't be write because I don't have the page in question bookmarked.  I clicked on a link while off VPN and was taken to virginmedia "advanced search" page.  Now I'm back on VPN when I click said link Safari still goes to "advanced search". Entering the URL in safari address bar shows it is choosing "top hits".  Deleting the link from History seems to do the trick.

Answer (score -3):

If you only want to remove the suggested search phrases, you can check Preferences > Privacy > Prevent search engine from providing suggestions. After that, there is only one item between the top hits and other results.

[image]